# Error: reading dictionary from json file: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, dictionary, blackjack

See error message and dictionary below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/richarddoi/Desktop/blackjack/test blackjack csv.py", line 9, in <module>
    for key,value in data:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

{'Ace of Hearts': 1, 'King of Hearts': 10, 'Queen of Hearts': 10, 'Jack of Hearts': 10, '10 of Hearts': 10, '9 of Hearts': 9, '8 of Hearts': 8, '7 of Hearts': 7, '6 of Hearts': 6, '5 of Hearts': 5, '4 of Hearts': 4, '3 of Hearts': 3, '2 of Hearts': 2, 'Ace of Spades': 1, 'King of Spades': 10, 'Queen of Spades': 10, 'Jack of Spades': 10, '10 of Spades': 10, '9 of Spades': 9, '8 of Spades': 8, '7 of Spades': 7, '6 of Spades': 6, '5 of Spades': 5, '4 of Spades': 4, '3 of Spades': 3, '2 of Spades': 2, 'Ace of Clubs': 1, 'King of Clubs': 10, 'Queen of Clubs': 10, 'Jack of Clubs': 10, '10 of Clubs': 10, '9 of Clubs': 9, '8 of Clubs': 8, '7 of Clubs': 7, '6 of Clubs': 6, '5 of Clubs': 5, '4 of Clubs': 4, '3 of Clubs': 3, '2 of Clubs': 2, 'Ace of Diamonds': 1, 'King of Diamonds': 10, 'Queen of Diamonds': 10, 'Jack of Diamonds': 10, '10 of Diamonds': 10, '9 of Diamonds': 9, '8 of Diamonds': 8, '7 of Diamonds': 7, '6 of Diamonds': 6, '5 of Diamonds': 5, '4 of Diamonds': 4, '3 of Diamonds': 3, '2 of Diamonds': 2}
```

This appears when I use the following code:

```
import json

with open('deckfile.json') as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

But at this point, when I try to print the key and the value, using this code:

```
    for key,value in data:
        print(key, value)
```

I get an error message. To date, I've used txt and binary files successfully. I've never used to a dictionary before in reading from a file.

My question is: what is meant by too many values? As far as I know, there is a dictionary with: the name of the card and the value of the card for every card in a 52 card deck. I used a convention to try to get the key and the value without a success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here are some guidelines for asking questions in order to get the most helpful responses from people: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcveph

Comment: Don't read it line by line.  Just read the whole file into `json.loads`.  If you want more help, you need to format this question.  Try backticks for inline code and four-space tabs for longer code.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge meant to post: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `for key,value in data`, there are two problems:

1. `data` is the list of dictionaries. You probably meant `for key,value in row`.
2. Iterating over a dictionary only iterates over its keys. To iterate over both keys and values, do `for key,value in row.items()`.

> My question is: what is meant by too many values?

`for key,value in data` means that `data` should be an iterable of pairs that get unpacked into `key` and `value`. But the first thing you get when iterating over `data` is the big dictionary it contains. To try to unpack the dictionary into `key, value`, Python iterates over the dictionary and gets all 52 keys, which is too many values.

Think of it this way: you wouldn't do:

```
for row in data:
    key, value = row
```

because the row has many keys and values. Nor would you do:

```
for k in row:
    key, value = k
```

because `k` is a key of `row`, which is a string. Hence we need `.items()`.

Comment: I read into json.loads. I added this code per your suggestion, Mr. Hall. 
  for key,value in row.items():
        print(key + " " + str(value)). This solved my question in a way that was swift and satisfactory. Thank you.